# SQL : Get common values of 2 variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Edit**: I have rephrased the original question to explain the scenario better.

**What I have?**

I have a table named Table1 with 5 columns A, B, C, D, E.

**What I require?**

Now from this table, i need to select only few columns which are stored in a variable @var1. This variable @var1 changes dynamically.

@var1 = 'A,B,F'

SET @sql = 'select ' + @var1 + ' from [Table1]

EXEC sp_executesql @sql.

This results in an error as the Column "F" is not available in the table "Table1"

**Problem:**

Now since the column "F" is not available in the table, I want the output table to contain only the columns A and B.

How do I arrive at such an output?

///
*How to get common values of 2 variables into another variable in sql?
I have a concatenated column names in two different variables as follows
**Example:**
    I have a concatenated column names in two different variables as follows.
    Variable 1:
    @columns1 = [ABC],[EFG],[MNO],[XYZ]
    Variable 2:
    @columns2 = sum([ABC]) as [ABC],sum([IJK]) as [IJK],sum([MNO]) as [MNO]
Result required:
    Since the column names [ABC] and [MNO] exist in both variables, my final output has to be like this.
    @finalColumns = [ABC],[MNO]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the values in both the variables

Then compare both the splitted rows. Then concatenate the matched rows with comma. something like this.

```
DECLARE @columns1 VARCHAR(max) = '[ABC],[EFG],[MNO],[XYZ]',
        @columns2 VARCHAR(max) = 'Sum([ABC]) as [ABC],sum([IJK]) as [IJK],sum([MNO]) as [MNO]',
        @result varchar(max)

set @result = (SELECT sp_col+','
FROM  (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') sp_col
       FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@columns1, ',', '</M><M>')
                            + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS F
              CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT sp_col
               FROM  (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') sp_col
                      FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@columns2, ',', '</M><M>')
                                           + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS S
                             CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))b
               WHERE  Charindex(a.sp_col, b.sp_col) > 0) 
               for xml path(''))

select @result = left(@result,LEN(@result)-1)

select @result  --[ABC],[MNO]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited the question to explain the scenario better. Could you please take a look?

Comment: You edit doesn't change the fact that all you want to do is string parsing and searching.

Comment: but is it possible to fetch the required columns ignoring the ones that are not available?

Answer (score 0):

It's an exercise in string parsing and not really SQL. Of course you could just grab one of the string splitting algorithms off the internet and use that.

```
declare @columns1 varchar(255) = '[ABC],[EFG],[MNO],[XYZ]';
declare @columns2 varchar(255) = 'SUM([ABC]) as [ABC],sum([IJK]) as [IJK],sum([MNO]) as [MNO]';
declare @p1 int = 0;
declare @p2 int = charindex(',', @columns1 + ',', @p1);
declare @s varchar(32);
declare @out varchar(256) = '';
declare @sep varchar(1) = '';

while @p2 > 0
begin
    set @s = substring(@columns1, @p1+1, @p2-@p1-1);
    if charindex(@s, @columns2) > 0
    begin
        set @out = @out + @sep + @s;
        set @sep = ',';
    end
    set @p1 = @p2;
    set @p2 = charindex(',', @columns1 + ',', @p1+1);
end
print @out
```